# Using plotly for a surface plot

Tags: python

I'm trying to plot the Surface plot using `plotly` command for the function `f(x,y)=x+y`.
The following is the code I use in Jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np


x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=np.linspace(-10,10,100)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z=x+y
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

trace=go.Surface(x=x,y=y,z=Z)
data=[trace]
fig=go.Figure(data=data)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

But unfortunately I'm only getting some thing like this:
[image]

Can someone please explain what I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I have put `x` instead of `X` in the `go.Surface`

Comment: if you find an answer to your issue, please mark it as the right answer, so nobody will go here trying solve it

Comment: @ginkul sure. But it doesn't allow me to do so before 48 hours

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. No problem, then!